# Language switch with query parameters using hook_language_switch_links_alter

Tags: i18n-l10n

I implemented `hook_language_switch_links_alter()` to preserve the query parameters while switching language.

```php
function custom_job_search_query_language_switch_links_alter(&$links, $type, $path) {
  $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  $query = drupal_http_build_query($params);  

  foreach ($links as &$link) {
    $link['query'] = $params;
    $link['href'] = $link['href'] . '?' . $query;
  }
}
```

The content of `$link` is the following.

```
Array(
  [ja] => Array(
    [href] => the-team/office-location?field_office_location_tid=All&field_job_category_tid=8168
    [title] => 日本語
    [language] => stdClass Object(
      [language] => ja
      [name] => Japanese
      [native] => 日本語
      [direction] => 0
      [enabled] => 1
      [plurals] => 0
      [prefix] => ja
      [weight] => 0
      [javascript] => ctbrOuYmjvFqegLO0dITk5UoiOqA6B0ydAybbphrNX0
    )
    [attributes] => Array(
      [class] => Array(
        [0] => language-link
      )
      [xml:lang] => ja
    )
    [query] => Array(
      [field_office_location_tid] => All
      [field_job_category_tid] => 8168
    )
  )
  [en-JPM] => Array(
    [href] => the-team/office-location?field_office_location_tid=All&field_job_category_tid=8168
    [title] => English
    [language] => stdClass Object(
      [language] => en-JPM
      [name] => JP-Specific
      [native] => English
      [direction] => 0
      [enabled] => 1
      [plurals] => 0
      [prefix] => en
      [weight] => 0
    )
    [attributes] => Array(
      [class] => Array(
        [0] => language-link
      )
      [xml:lang] => en-JPM
    )
    [query] => Array(
      [field_office_location_tid] => All
      [field_job_category_tid] => 8168
    )
  )
)
```

The query parameters are appended as `the-team/office-location%3Ffield_office_location_tid%3DAll%26field_job_category_tid%3D8168` and the URL is not correct.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you hope that code will do? Currently, even if you fix the obvious parameter encoding problem, all links will be identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue using the following code.

```php
/**
* Implements hook_url_outbound_alter().
*/
function custom_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  // Always make login/logout links go to the current page.
  switch ($path) {
    case 'user/logout':
    case 'user/login':
      $options['query']['destination'] = $_GET['q'];
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question is wrong because, in [`hook_language_switch_links_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/7.x), you should not append the query string to `$link['href']`, but set `$link['query']`.

```php
function custom_job_search_query_language_switch_links_alter(&$links, $type, $path) {
  $query = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  
  foreach ($links as &$link) {
    $link['query'] = $query;
  }
}
```